# Pythonic way of observing a variable in multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading

Imagine having the two threads `observeT` and `upT`. `observeT` observes the value of an instance attribute (`instance.a`) and should 'alert' (print a note in this example) if its value is `7`. Then there's the thread `upT`, which increases the value of the instance attribute by 1 at a time (`instance.a` += 1).

However, due to the randomly chosen thread to continue with Python's `Lock` we can't make sure that the observer thread (`observeT`) catches the moment when the value of `instance.a` was increased to `7`.

How do I make sure that the observer is called every time after `upT` releases to lock? Note that it is important to keep the threads `upT` and `observeT` split.

Please see the following code for more details:

```
from threading import Lock, Thread


class MyClass():
    a: int

    def __new__(cls):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.a = 0
        return instance

instance = MyClass()
lock = Lock()

def up():
    for i in range(100000):
        with lock:
            instance.a += 1

def observe():
    while True:
        with lock:
            a = instance.a
            if a == 7:
                print("This is 7!")
            if instance.a == 100000:
                break

observeT = Thread(target=observe)
upT = Thread(target=up)

observeT.start()
upT.start()

upT.join()
observeT.join()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Side Note: Your main thread calls `upT.start()` and then it immediately calls `upT.join()`. That means, your main thread doesn't do anything _concurrently_ with the `upT` thread. But, concurrency is the only reason for having threads.  So why create the `upT` thread at all? The main thread already exists. Why not use it? Why not just do: `observeT.start(); up(); observeT.join()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
from threading import Thread, Lock, Condition


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a_lock):
        self.cond = Condition(a_lock)
        self.canproceed = False
        self.a = 0

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
        if key == 'a':
            if value == 7 or value == 100000:
                self.cond.notify()
                if value == 7:
                    while not self.canproceed:
                        self.cond.wait()


lock = Lock()
instance = MyClass(lock)


def up():
    for i in range(100000):
        with lock:
            instance.a += 1


def observe():
    with instance.cond:
        while instance.a != 7:
            instance.cond.wait()
        print("This is 7!")
        instance.canproceed = True
        instance.cond.notify()
        while instance.a != 100000:
            instance.cond.wait()




observeT = Thread(target=observe)
upT = Thread(target=up)

observeT.start()
upT.start()

upT.join()
observeT.join()
```

Output:

```
This is 7!
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is it!

Comment: Hi, I have one more question: Let's say we can't change `up()` and everything `up()` does is increasing `instance.a`, like this: `with cond:
 instance.a += 1` ... how can I make `observe()` still notices that change?

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3 If that's the case, you can't guarantee that `observe` will notice when `a` becomes exactly `7`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the exact scenario I have ... any workarounds or other solutions?

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3 In your post, which pieces of code are you not allowed to modify?

Comment: The `up()` method

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3 Updated to reflect your scenario where the `up` method is untouched.

Comment: Thank you! Will take a look into